# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error when upgrading to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I tried to upgrade an existing project from Rails 3.2.3 to Rails 4.1.4(the latest). I updated my gemfile and had no problems updating the bundle. I also added

```
config.eager_load = false
```

to my environment *.rb. When I run the server I get the following error when I try to access the first page… It looks like no connection to database but I can use a client to access it. My service currently uses sqlite3..

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
>   (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in`retrieve_connection'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in`restore_query_cache_settings'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in`call'
>       activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in
>   `call'
>       actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>       activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'    (1.5.2) li

b/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
   …

My database.yml file did not change. It uses sqlite3

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that when migrating from 3.2 to 4.0 there are quite a few changes to apply to the configuration files. You can see the details in the link below, I was able to solve the problem using postgres instead of sqlite and running the command suggested by the link

```
rake rails:update
```

[Upgrading to rails 4.0 from 3.2](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/06/upgrading-to-rails-4-0-from-rails-3-2-test-case-part-i-preparations-configuration-gems/)